# How to download files with a specific extension only from an FTP server?

Tags: downloads, ftp, bittorrent, filezilla

I'd like to batch download `.torrent` files from a FTP server (e.g. ftp://ftp.fau.de/gimp/gimp/) with one command or one click in a GUI (after entering the hostname and the root directory). The aim is to have all the `.torrent` file under a root on the FTP server in a directory so that they can be batch added to a torrent client, like Deluge GTK.

In Filezilla I still have to open all directories and click on all of the torrent files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wget supports [recursive download](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options) and [accept lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options) which should cover this use case.

```
wget -r -np -A "*.torrent" ftp://ftp.fau.de/gimp/gimp/
```

The file-extension should be specified.

The command will recursively download all files ending in torrent from ftp://ftp.fau.de/gimp/gimp/ .

If you want to remove the directory structure and have all files in the current working direcotory add `-nd` to the argument list.

If you want to skip downloads for files which already exist in the target directory, add `-nc` to the argument list.

Comment: Thank you. Any way to avoid downloading a file twice if it's found at more than one location, like on http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ (not FTP, but the above works as well) (there's no duplicate file created, but the download is unnecessary)?

Comment: @KarlRichter you might find a solution for that here? (unless I've misunderstood the problem) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944295/skip-download-if-files-exist-in-wget